# Gamma gallery with masonry li elements overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry

I have an issue with my gallery load more button.

I am using pretty old script Gamma Gallery. You can see this on link here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/06/gamma-gallery-a-responsive-image-gallery-experiment/

My problem is: when i click on "Show more" button li elements are overlaping. Sometimes position counts correctly, sometimes not and I don't know why. I spent on it last 8 hours and I need "fresh look on it" by you wise guys.

All scripts are correctly loaded. Below you can see simple list which is loading fine:

```
<div class="gamma-container gamma-loading" id="gamma-container">
<ul class="gamma-gallery">
    <li>
        <div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Citroen Banner</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350">
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg"></div>
            <noscript>
                <img src="/img/realizacje/citroen.jpg" alt="img03" />
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Euro Laser Clinic Logo</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350">
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div>
            <div data-src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg"></div>
            <noscript>
                <img src="/img/realizacje/laser.jpg" alt="img03" />
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </li>
    ... 
   div class="gamma-overlay"></div>
<div id="loadmore" class="loadmore">Wczytaj więcej naszych realizacji</div>
```

And that how i init script:

```
jQuery(function() {

            var GammaSettings = {
                    // order is important!
                    viewport : [ {
                        width : 1200,
                        columns : 5
                    }, {
                        width : 900,
                        columns : 4
                    }, {
                        width : 500,
                        columns : 3
                    }, { 
                        width : 320,
                        columns : 2
                    }, { 
                        width : 0,
                        columns : 2
                    } ]
            };

            Gamma.init( GammaSettings, fncallback );
```

//

```
            var page = 0
            , items = ['<li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>PrzyodniaZalesie</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/obraz3.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li><li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Mucha&Lech</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/obraz4.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li><li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>PrzychodniaZalesie</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/obraz5.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li><li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Mucha&Lech</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/obraz6.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li><li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>PrzyodniaZalesie</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/obraz7.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li><li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Mucha&Lech</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/obraz8.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li><li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Mucha&Lech</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/obraz9.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li><li><div data-alt="img03" data-description="<h3>Play</h3>" data-max-width="1800" data-max-height="1350"><div data-src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg" data-min-width="1300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg" data-min-width="1000"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg" data-min-width="700"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg" data-min-width="300"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg" data-min-width="200"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg" data-min-width="140"></div><div data-src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg"></div><noscript><img src="/img/realizacje/play.jpg" alt="img03"/></noscript></div></li>']



                function fncallback() {   
                $(' #loadmore ').show().on( 'click', function() {

                    ++page;
                    var newitems = items[page-1];
                    if( page <= 1 ) {
                        Gamma.add( $( newitems ) );
                    }
                    if( page == 1 ) {

                        $( this ).remove();

                    };

                });                           
               }
        });
```

In table "items" is minified list and this I am trying to load on click. But li element positions are counting wrong.

You can see it on website [nowy.drukarniacreative.pl/realizacje](http://nowy.drukarniacreative.pl/realizacje)

I will be glad if you can help me.

Comment: Where's your masonry code?

Comment: http://nowy.drukarniacreative.pl/js/gamma/jquery.masonry.min.js

Comment: I was actually asking about the code to call masonry, not masonry.js.